# WildFly - Application deployment issues related to trying to resolve security vulnerabilities

Tags: java, docker, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

## Introduction

So, at this moment in time I'm currently working with AKS, my team is currently utilising TwistLock & we've noticed a critical vulnerability with the base docker image that we're using. I was just wondering if anyone knew of a clean way in which we could get this to behave as expected?

## My Primitive Solution

So, to get pass the critical vulnerability, I've implemented the following snippet into our Dockerfile, I've mostly done this as a test, I had very little hope that it would actually work. Surprisingly it works more than what I had imagined, but without further ado here's the code:

```sh
## Remove dependencies for twistlock.
RUN rm -r /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/
RUN rm -r /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org/apache/commons/beanutils/
RUN rm -r /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org/picketlink/
RUN rm -r /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/client
```

I decided to manually try to remove the dependencies associated with WildFly itself, **but** without surprise, this resulted in the applications failing to successfully deploy.

### Additional

Even if I specify the dependencies in the pom file like so, it still doesn't work:

```xml
<!-- ... Other parts of the pom ... -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.10</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.10</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.10</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<!-- ... Other parts of the pom ... -->
```

I've also tried including a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file, with the following code:

```xml
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

## The Output

It's not surprise that I get the following error in the logs, but I was wondering if it's at all possible to get past this problem:

[image: Screenshot of the log file, without the name of the application that I'm working on.]

## Conclusion

Obviously my far from suitable solution doesn't work & unfortunately JBoss/WildFly configuration/administration is far from being one of my specialist areas.

Does anyone have any possible solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Thankfully, after an array of attempts to tinker with this problem, I believe that I have found the most suitable solution, thankfully it would appear that I was on the right lines, however I needed to just add a little extra. It was as simple as updating my `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file to utilise the following markup:

```xml
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations" />

            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I've successfully been able to deploy the application that I'm working on, I've now only one more vulnerability which goes beyond the scope of the application layer.